# NodeJs construct Excel file and export in PDF

Tags: node.js, excel, pdf

As the title said, I'm searching for a NodeJS library to construct Excel (xlsx), with cell format (color, font size, images...). Importantly, it must has the capability of exporting the resulted .xlsx file to .pdf format.

I know some libs that call Excel API but I'm running a linux server and that's impossible for me.

Comment: Building an XLSX file and generating a PDF are two different things... What it is you actually want? A PDF?

Comment: I want to contruct an in-memory xlsx (which some libs can easily do: node-xlxs, exceljs...), and then save that file as .pfd format. None of the libs mentioned can do that, AFAIN.
I worked in an .NET project before, there was actually an paid lib which can do that.

Comment: Why do you need to

Comment: I’m building a website that can manage and export the order. I want pdf because it’s portable and printable.

Comment: Ah sorry previous comment was sent incomplete. The question was why do you need to generate an XLS first? Why not generate the PDF directly? You would have more flexibility.

Comment: Oh, great, thank you. I didn't think about that. I'll try then update the result.
Previously my client needed the Excel file, but I'll try to convince them about pdf only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to jcaron comment I finally found out that I can build a PDF file directly without passing through xls.
I used [pdfmaker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake) for nodejs that support creating PDF file pretty well.